# Scrollbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i would hide scroll bar in singlechildscrollview but for some reason my code doesn't work, scrollbar is still visible.

That's my code:

```dart
class CoffeeStoriesContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const CoffeeStoriesContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      thickness: 0,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 900,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly isn’t working?

Comment: scrollbar is still visible

Comment: Why not just remove ScrollbarWidget if you want to hide the indicator?

Answer (score 0):

Use controller
Define the controller

```
final ScrollController _firstController = ScrollController();
```

Then use it in the

```
Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  controller: _firstController,
)
```

The full code example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final ScrollController _firstController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
              // Only one scroll position can be attached to the
              // PrimaryScrollController if using Scrollbars. Providing a
              // unique scroll controller to this scroll view prevents it
              // from attaching to the PrimaryScrollController.
              child: Scrollbar(
                isAlwaysShown: true,
                controller: _firstController,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _firstController,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text('Scrollable 1 : Index $index'),
                    );
                  }
                ),
              )
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
              // This vertical scroll view has not been provided a
              // ScrollController, so it is using the
              // PrimaryScrollController.
              child: Scrollbar(
                isAlwaysShown: true,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: index.isEven
                          ? Colors.amberAccent
                          : Colors.blueAccent,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text('Scrollable 2 : Index $index'),
                      )
                    );
                  }
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        );
    });
  }
}
```